# How to simulate on iphone4S in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I found that there is a problem with my app on iPhone 4s only .
In xcode, under hardware , i cant see iPhone4s but only `3.5 and 4.5 inch iphones` .
How can i test an app to a specific device in xcode ?
I somehow couldnt find an answer for that .
(my device is iPhone4 )

Thanks a lot .

Comment: It shouldn't be dependent on the device but rather on the version of iOS installed (though I guess it could have something to do with timings or memory which is device dependent). Also, testing in the simulator isn't a substitute for testing on real devices so you really should get some more devices to test with.

Comment: thanks a lot. so i cant test on a specific device on simulator ?

Comment: No not in any way that I'm aware of at least. But as I said, the problems mostly stems from variations in iOS-versions and not hardware.